# Why is the clip of "Stefan pouring tea on his keyboard" played so many times?

Tags: black-mirror, bandersnatch

In *Black Mirror: Bandersnatch* (2018), Stefan poured tea on his keyboard because the game he designed failed to execute.

In the next scene, a video of "Stefan pouring tea on his keyboard" played so many times in one of the two CRT monitors that I thought my computer caught a virus. I only realized what was happening by seeing the video timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't only his keyboard - this was the whole computer.

[image]

By spilling the drink he makes the computer to short-circuit. The meta-joke then makes your video is also damaged by his damage, which makes it little ambiguous who is controlling who.